# Type 'Router' not found.Method not found: 'Router',even I've imported

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
import 'package:fluro/fluro.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide Router;
import 'package:flutter_scaffold/route/router_handler.dart';

final route = Router();

class Routes {
  static GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey();

  // 路由页面配置
  static String root = "/";
  static String incrementCounter = '/incrementCounter';

  static void configureRoutes(Router router) {
    router.define(root, handler: mainHandler);
    router.define(Routes.incrementCounter, handler: incrementCounterHandler);
  }
```

when I run flutter run ,the below error occurs
[image]

I upgraded the fluro ==>  fluro: ^2.0.3 for support null-safety

the code can run without errors at before.

if I change `import 'package:fluro/fluro.dart'; import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide Router;` to `import 'package:fluro/fluro.dart'; import 'package:flutter/material.dart';`

IDE can't find Router

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide Router;
```

line says that you intend to `import` everything **except** `Router` from that particular source. So, not seeing `Router` is expected behavior. You may want to change it to

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

EDIT

It turned out that `Router` was renamed to `FluroRouter` and the code needed to reflect that as well as it needed to be installed. After John ran

```
flutter pub get
```

it worked!

Comment: if I change like that it will says can't find Router,see above

Comment: @John can you tell me which package should contain `Router` from the packages you import?

Comment: as I know before version both 'package:fluro/fluro.dart' and 'package:flutter/material.dart' contain Router,so I the second line add 'hide'.i don't know about the new version

Comment: @John you need to check the origin of it in the new version. If it has changed its location or name, then that's the problem.

Comment: @John other answers are saying that the `Router` class has been removed and `FluroRouter` is the new name.

Comment: yeah,I've tried FluroRouter. see the last pic I posted

Comment: @John what is your error now and what is the warning in line 1?

Comment: the error is` not found the FluroRouter`, never mind ,after I run 'flutter pub get' ,it works fine

Comment: @John thanks for the info! I have edited my answer accordingly, so future visitors will instantly know the solution we figured out here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
final router = FluroRouter();
```

Comment: I've tried ,complains other error

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in  https://github.com/lukepighetti/fluro/releases the Router class has been removed since version 1.7.0 and replaced by FluroRouter later on

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import 'package:campus/router/i_router.dart';
import 'package:campus/router/not_found_page.dart';
import 'package:campus/screens/home.dart';
import 'package:campus/screens/webview/webview_router.dart';
import 'package:fluro/fluro.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Routes {
  static String home = '/home';
  
  static final List<IRouterProvider> _listRouter = [];

  static final FluroRouter router = FluroRouter();

  static void initRoutes() {

    /// Specify route jump error return page
    router.notFoundHandler = Handler(
        handlerFunc: (BuildContext? context, Map<String, List<String>> params) {
      debugPrint('init router');
      return const NotFoundPage();
    });

    router.define(home,
        handler: Handler(
            handlerFunc:
                (BuildContext? context, Map<String, List<String>> params) =>
                    const Home()));



    _listRouter.clear();

    _listRouter.add(SettingRouter());
 
    void initRouter(IRouterProvider routerProvider) {
      routerProvider.initRouter(router);
    }

    _listRouter.forEach(initRouter);
  }
}
```

then implement this

```
import 'package:fluro/fluro.dart';

abstract class IRouterProvider {
  void initRouter(FluroRouter router);
}
```

as you see in the first code block in   `_listRouter.add(SettingRouter());`
The respective routes are managed by their respective modules,
and the initialization is added here uniformly.
to implement module of route use this code :

```
import 'package:campus/router/i_router.dart';
import 'package:campus/screens/webview/webview.dart';
import 'package:fluro/fluro.dart';


class SettingRouter implements IRouterProvider {
  static String settingPage = '/setting';
  static String settingLanguage = '/setting/language';

  @override
  void initRouter(FluroRouter router) {
    router.define(settingPage,
        transitionType: TransitionType.fadeIn,
        handler: Handler(handlerFunc: (_, __) => const WebView()));
    // router.define(settingLanguage,
    //     handler: Handler(handlerFunc: (_, __) => const LanguageAndLocale()));
     }
}
```